# Bluebird promise and alias

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Is there a way to pass in the array of promises so you can access the results by a given alias rather than the index? Without using Props.

Like this sort of thing:

```
var a = [{shop: promise(customer)},{customer:promise(customer)}]

Promise.all(a).then(function(res){
    console.log(res.shop):
});
```

Props can used for this, however it doesn't fit my requirements but here's how it is done with props in case anyone needs it:

```
Promise.props({
    pictures: getPictures(),
    comments: getComments(),
    tweets: getTweets()
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.tweets, result.pictures, result.comments);
});
```

Comment: Your missunderstanding of arrays and objects is not really connected to bluebird/promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own version of `.all()` that would do what you're asking for like this:

```
Promise.allProp = function(arrayOfObjects) {
    var promises, keys = [];
    arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = Object.keys(item)[0];      // use first property only
        promises.push(item[key]);
        keys.push(key);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        // combine results array back with keys
        var obj = {};
        return results.forEach(function(r, index) {
            obj[keys[index]] = r;
        })
        return obj;
    });
}
```

You pass it an array of objects like

```
[{shop:  funcAPromise()}, {customer: funcAPromise()}]
```

And, the resolved value of the resulting promise would be an object with one result for each property name.

```
{shop:  funcAResolvedValue, customer: funcBResolvedValue}
```

Usage:

```
var array = [{shop:  funcAPromise()}, {customer: funcAPromise()}];
Promise.allWithProps(array).then(function(results) {
   console.log(results);   // {shop:  funcAResolvedValue, customer: funcBResolvedValue}
});
```

---

Or, if you're using Bluebird already, it might be easier to massage the input array to fit what `Promise.props()` wants and use it directly:

```
Promise.allProp = function(arrayOfObjects) {
    var obj = {};
    arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
        obj[key] = item[key];
    });
    return Promise.props(obj);
}
```

---

If it bothers you to extend the Promise object and you already have Bluebird, then you could just make a helper function that modifies your array of objects into the single object that `Promise.props()` wants:

```
 function convertToObject(array) {
    var obj = {};
    array.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
        obj[key] = item[key];
    });
    return obj;
 }

 Promise.props(convertToObject(myInputArrayOfObjects)).then(function(r) {
     console.log(r.tweets);
     console.log(r.comments);
 });
```

---

**Note:** These solutions all assume you won't have more than one promise for the same property name and that each incoming object only has one property name.  There are slightly different behaviors if there's more than one object with the same property name.

The first `Promise.allProp()` will actually await on all promises, but return only the resolved result for the last one.

The second `Promise.allProp()` and the `convertToObject()` solution will only await on the last conflicting promise if any are conflicting and return that last resolved result.

Either of the first two solutions could be changed to include all properties on the incoming objects (not just the first property) if desired.

---

**More General Purpose Implementation**

Here's a bit more general purpose solution with error checking on input property conflicts.  This works with generic ES6 promises and supercedes Bluebird's `Promise.props()` for functionality because this will accept both a single object with a list of properties or an array of objects each with a list of properties.

It will process all the property/value pairs on all the objects.  It will throw an exception if it sees a given property name appear on more than one object - they must all be unique because that's the only way to communicate the results back in a single object with property/value pairs where value is the resolved value of the incoming promise.

Here's the more general purpose implementation.

```
// Takes a single object or an array of objects 
//   where each object has one or more keys/value pairs
// The values are all promises which should be combined and waited on with Promise.all()
// The keys must all be unique across all the objects in the array,
//   the same key cannot appear in any other object
// The resolved value is a single object with key/value pairs where the value is the
//     resolved value of all the incoming promises
Promise.allProp = function(obj) {
    try {
        var arrOfObjErr = "Must pass an object or array of objects to .allProp()";
        if (typeof obj !== "object") {
            throw new Error(arrOfObjErr);
        }
        // if just a single object was passed, then put it in an array so the general array processing code works
        var arr = Array.isArray(obj) ? obj : [obj];
        var promises = [], keys = [], keyMap = {};
        arr.forEach(function(item) {
            if (typeof item !== "object") {
                throw new Error(arrOfObjErr);
            }
            Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
                if (keyMap[key]) {
                    throw new Error("Conflicting property name '" + key + "' - all property names must be unique");
                } else {
                    // show key has already been used
                    keyMap[key] = true;
                    // save promise and key in separate arrays
                    promises.push(item[key]);
                    keys.push(key);
                }
            });
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // turn any synchronous exceptions into a rejection so the caller doesn't have to use try/catch
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
    // await all promises, then combine resolved results with original keys into a single object
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        // combine results array back with keys
        var obj = {};
        results.forEach(function(result, index) {
            obj[keys[index]] = result;
        })
        // resolve with a single object full of key/value pairs
        return obj;
    });
}
```

In the implementation, it iterates through all the objects passed in and collects a separate array of promises and a corresponding array of keys.  The array of promises is waited on with `Promise.all()` and then when those promises are all done, it processes the resolved result for each promise back into an object with the original property name.  The final resolved result is a single object with property/value pairs on it.

If any conflicting keys are found, it will reject with a descriptive error message.

```
// example of single object
Promise.allProp({tweets: p1, comments: p2}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.tweets);
    console.log(result.comments);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

// example of array of objects
Promise.allProp([{tweets: p1, comments: p2}, {pictures: p3}]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.tweets);
    console.log(result.comments);
    console.log(result.pictures);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

// example of illegal same property appearing on more than one object
Promise.allProp([{tweets: p1, comments: p2}, {tweets: p3, pictures: p4}, ]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.tweets);
    console.log(result.comments);
    console.log(result.pictures);
}, function(err) {
    // will reject because of "tweets" property appearing on more than one object
    console.log(err);
});
```

Test cases for the code: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uamxax4e/

Comment: Thank you. I shall give it ago - had hoped I didn't have to extend the library, but this might just do the trick.

Comment: @AlexC - I added another option to my answer.

Comment: Cheers! Solved the problem.

Comment: @AlexC - I added one more choice.

Comment: @AlexC - I added a more general purpose implementation that will take either a single object with one or more properties or an array of objects each with one or more properties and will also reject if there are conflicting property names to prevent accidental overwriting of property names.

Comment: Thanks you, all sorted!

Answer (score 3):

No `Promise.all()` works exclusively with arrays, but with ES6:

```
const a = [promise(customer), promise(customer)];
Promise.all(a)
  .then(([shop, customer]) => console.log(shop))
```

Or, alternatively, with Bluebird's `Promise.prototype.spread()`

```
var a = [promise(customer), promise(customer)];
Promise.all(a)
  .spread(function(shop, customer) {
    console.log(shop);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give the spread a go or might have to find a work around with props.